# Mono Fiddler - Can't descrypt HTTPS

Tags: mono, ssl-certificate, fiddler

I can't import Fiddler SSL certificate 
http://screencloud.net/v/gRly
http://screencloud.net/v/28jk

Comment: How specifically did you generate the CRT/PEM file from Fiddler's .CER file?

Comment: @EricLaw I've used this command openssl x509 -inform der -in FiddlerRoot.cer -out FiddlerRoot.crt